# How do I change one tag to another (a slightly different one)?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've accidentally created a new tag (or so it seems): `vertex-buffer` while posting a question. Then in another question I needed a tag about index buffer so I tried `index-buffer` and found out that `index-buffers` (plural) already existed. So I used that one.

Then I thought - both tags should be consistent - either both plural or both singural. So I wanted to change my `vertex-buffer` in the first question to `vertex-buffers` but I couldn't because it was similar to already existing... well, `vertex-buffer` (**the very one I was trying to change!**). So I couldn't. Couldn't use the plural `vertex-buffers` in the new question for the same reason.

Please, tell me how I can make them consistent or do that for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I merged all tags of `vertex-buffers` into `vertex-buffer` and all tags of `index-buffers` into `index-buffer`. Originally I did the opposite, but it looks like the majority of our master tags are singular in nature.

The merge destination tags were not otherwise used, so I didn't create a synonym; this was a one-time merge.

Comment: I'm not sure if this counts as an answer but this whole topic is not about questions and answers, really. :P

Comment: I suppose what I meant to be implicit in my "answer" was that *you* can't do what you were asking for directly (it requires either a certain reputation gate to propose synonyms or a moderator to merge tags). You could have waited a while and I think the unused tag would fall out of the system, but I'm not sure. :)

Comment: @JoshPetrie There's a script that destroys "zombie tags" (tags with no questions) once per day, at 3:00 AM, IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem, can't you remove the tag, save, edit again and add the similar one?

More general, I think questions with tags which are synonyms should be automatically replaced by one of those synonyms, for consistency.

I am not sure if a server side workaround exists, but otherwise you wouldn't get all questions of *contentual one* tag, but only of one *specific synonym* in the search results.

Comment: Nice idea but unfortunately it doesn't work. Even when a tag isn't used at all, it still persists in the system.

Comment: Ahh, so the issue is that a similar tag already exists in the system. Then this might be part of a moderator's job. But I don't know how to contact one for this subject.